# Can anyone help me understand what causes this error ? OPTIX_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE in optixAccelComputeMemoryUsage

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, denoise

I m trying to do a rendering with optix on.
I just recently upgraded from 2060 to a 3090.
I had the exact same error with the 2060 but i thought it was because of vram limiation as the scene that i want to render is approx 8Gb.

This is what i get in blenger log
[image]

My computer specs are:

CPU AMD 3900X

64Gb 3200Mhz Ram

Nvma SSD Disk

NVIDIA MSI SUPRIM X RTX3090

Blender 2.91.0 - Rendering Engine Cycles

Any advise is highly appreciated!

Comment: Related https://devtalk.blender.org/t/solved-optix-denoiser-error-with-2-91-alpha-optix-error-invalid-value-in-optixmodulecreatefromptx/14638/3    tl;dr Disable Luxcore render engine

Comment: but i dont have luxcore installed...

Comment: One user also commented "The problem was that there was something corrupt in the userpref.blend, deleting it and reconfiguring blender solved the problem.

I’m not sure why this happened." Have you tried this?

Comment: Just uninstalled Blender and re-install it and also delete the userpref.blend. I still get the same error :(

Comment: Have you tried updating your graphics drivers?

Comment: Yes I have the latest drivers and also i tried both studio and gaming drivers.

Comment: Have the same issue. Everything was working fine until new Nvidia drivers. Tried studio and gameready.. Tried 2.82, 2.91. 2.92 and get the same error. In 2.91 I get sometimes EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in 2.92 OPTIX_Error